# Why get 100 reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I've just got a surge of 100 "zorkmids" on every of my accounts. I don't object, but I can't find any information why that happened.

Comment: I removed the last part of your question because people are not supposed to post answers in comments, and you shouldn't encourage them to do so, and really, that part isn't relevant to the question. (You should also know that you don't gain or lose reputation for meta posts.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5851/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic should I delete this question? I have got a satisfying answer so if this is a duplicate I don't insist on wasting disk space.

Comment: @Qmechanic or should this question be kept to *catch and redirect* future searches?

Comment: ^ ^ The latter.

Comment: @Qmechanic fine by me. So what happens if I click on the "That solved my problem" button? Will it just signal that the question is settled, or will it trigger something else, too?

Comment: I suspect it will close your question, but have a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22that+solved+my+problem%22).

Comment: @Qmechanic "Closing" will not make it dysfunctional in view of *catch and redirect*, or will it? I feel we agree on the goals, so please tell me the shortest way ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

-- from [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) in Help Center

Comment: Oh, I see, I quite unexpectedly earned some reputation on an old thing quite out of scope that lifted me over the 200-mark. Thanks for your answer!